# Android - Local Server Interaction

Tags: android

I am working on Android App which needs to communicate with the server. How to make android app to communicate to the Local server(http://www.localhost/) that setup in my machine for development purpose ?

Comment: Are you using emulator? All devices are on same network?

Comment: Which operating system is your server running?

Comment: @daentech, I am using ubuntu.

Comment: @Wakim, Am using the Nexus 4 device, Right now Nexus 4 and Ubuntu system are on the different network. But i am connect both to the same network.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you need to do two things:

1. Configure the server to bind to IP address other than 127.0.0.1. If you are talking about GAE DevServer, you do that by passing an argument like `--address=0.0.0.0`
2. You change your code to connect to the server's IP address on the LAN. Something like 192.168.xxx.xxx